# Make a copy of the audio output into a file

Tags: linux, audio

How to get the sound that I can hear in my headphones into a file or into a variable in my C/C++ program?
I'd like something like the framebuffer for images.
My main goal is sending sound to another computer, so I need read-write permissions also.
Anyone know how deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a test recording like so:

```
arecord -d 4 out.wav
```

You could use `dd` like this:

```
dd bs=1 if=out.wav | aplay
```

Or use a really choppy unbuffered stream with a while loop:

```
while read -n 2048 bytes; do
   printf "$bytes" | aplay
done < out.wav
```

You could then use `netcat` to redirect it to a socket or port.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739196/simple-socket-server-in-bash

The sound playing through the speakers may be buffered already in a file. I am not sure where that file would be located, but it might also be possible to `tail -f` or `cat` or pipe it to a different location with `netcat` or something similar.

For example using `ALSA` pcm:

- http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html
- http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html

Also consider taking a look at the source code for PulseAudio or using the real time transfer protocol (rtp) :

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network